# How do I increase the textbox size of a row in Struts2jquery grid?

Tags: jqgrid, struts2, struts2-jquery

```xml
<sjg:gridColumn name="scenarioDescription"
                index="scenarioDescription"
                title="Scenario Description" 
                sortable="true"
                editable="true" 
                edittype="text" />
```

***I tried using width="250" inside the tag but it is not working. I am new to jquery. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance**.*

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Struts2 myself. In general jqGrid allows to set *any* standard option of edit control inside of `editoptions`. For example the usage of

```js
editoptions: {size:10, maxlength: 15}
```

adds `size="10"` and `maxlength="15"` attributes of the `<input>` element created during editing.

If I look in [the documentation](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/EditGrid) of grid part of struts2-jquery it seems that you can specify `editoptions` by adding `editoptions` attribute to the `<sjg:gridColumn>` element. You can try something like

```xml
<sjg:gridColumn name="scenarioDescription"
                title="Scenario Description" 
                editable="true"
                editoptions="{size: 10, maxlength: 15}" />
```

The exact values of attributes `size`, `maxlength` or other you can choose corresponds your requirements.